# How to calculate screen size in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I calculate screen size in jQuery?

I have a script which creates a new chat window, but when I create the fourth window it appears off the screen. I would help to know how to calculate the size of the screen and not pass that limit!

```
function createChatBox(chatboxtitle,chatname,minimizeChatBox) {
  $(" <div />" )
    .attr("id","chatbox_"+chatboxtitle)
    .addClass("chatbox")
    .html('<div style="cursor:pointer"onclick="javascript:toggleChatBoxGrowth(\''+chatboxtitle+'\')"><div class="chatboxhead"><div class="chatboxtitle">'+chatname+'</div><div id="chatboxoptions"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:closeChatBox(\''+chatboxtitle+'\')"> X </a></div><br clear="all"/></div><div class="chatboxcontent"></div><div class="chatboxinput"><textarea class="chatboxtextarea" onkeydown="javascript:return checkChatBoxInputKey(event,this,\''+chatboxtitle+'\',\''+chatname+'\');"></textarea> <br clear="all"/></div>')
    .appendTo($( "body" ));

  $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('bottom', '0px');
  chatBoxeslength = 0;

  for (x in chatBoxes) {
    if ($("#chatbox_"+chatBoxes[x]).css('display') != 'none') {
    }
  }

  if (chatBoxeslength == 0) {
    $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('right', '215px');
  } else {
    width = (chatBoxeslength)*(225+7)+215;
    $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('right', width+'px');
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include the html so we know what you are working around

Comment: Do you mean the browser viewport? In jQuery `$(window).width()` should be all you need for that if so. (for native js just use the `screen` object)

Comment: what you need is the viewport size, screen size wont help

Answer (score 3):

Jquery `width()` function will give you the window width.

```
$(window).width()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable that equals the window width, and then plug it in into your code as needed. See the example below wand edit as needed.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
alert(windowWidth);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.write( window.outerWidth  );
```